# Flattening a list of mixed iterable and non-iterable objects

Tags: python, list

Yes, I know this topic has been covered before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158395/flatten-an-irregular-list-of-lists) but my question is concentrating in the case where the list has a maximal depth of 2 (i.e has objects of type *list* or *int*)

I have a list composed of iterable (i.e. lists) and non-iterable objects (i.e. integers) and I want to unpack all the iterable objects.
Here is an example of the functionality I'm trying to implement:

```
list_of_items = [[0, 1], 2, 3]
flatten_list = []
for x in list_of_items:
    if hasattr(x, '__iter__'):
        flatten_list.extend(x) 
    else:
        flatten_list.append(x)
print(flatten_list)
```

output:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3]
```

I'm looking for a more *pythonic* way or elegant one-liner solution with equivalent functionality

Comment: Honestly, this code is already pretty clear. A comprehension might arguably be more idiomatic, but I think I'd stick with something similar to what you already have. The only issue I see is it's easy to miss the `append`/`extend` difference.

Answer (score 2):

With your constraints (max 2 level depth, only list of int/list) you can do:

```py
out = [v for i in list_of_items for v in (i if isinstance(i, list) else [i])]
print(out)
```

Prints:

```py
[0, 1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Beat me to it. Although I must say that personally I do not think this is very readable - but it is what OP requested. Also, isinstance of `Iterable` might be the more general solution here (from ABC).